# Change value in a cell and update another cell in MySql table using Update query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have  MySQL table with with 5 columns. Product_id, product_name, pack_size , price and price change.

I have a requirement that if the value in **price cell** changes, it should update the cell value and save the updated value in **price_change** cell as well.

For example, in the dbfiddle attached, in the row 1, if price for eggs change from 1 to 3 , this means the new value in the price cell should be 3 and the price_chnage cell should be updated with old and new value 1,3.

[Mysql Table Example](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a9bc570e0e478b060494cf332e90532b)

The output should look something like this :
[image]

Not sure if this is achievable but there is not harm in asking :)
Thank you
Your help will be highly appreciated

Comment: The only option I can see is the trigger.

Comment: Storing as CSV is a bad idea and you have no idea when the change occurred, consider an archive table instead

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't suggest using your current schema, as storing the history of prices in a single data point, in CSV format, is not very usable or even scalable.  Instead, I recommend creating an archive table into which you would insert a backup of the previous row, along with a timestamp.  The insert operation would happen from a trigger after every update to your current main table.

```sql
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER trigger_after_update
AFTER UPDATE ON yourTable FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN

    INSERT INTO yourTableBackup (Product_id, Product_name, Pack_size, price, ts_of_backup)
    VALUES
        (NEW.Product_id, NEW.Product_name, NEW.Pack_size, NEW.price, NOW());

END;
//
DELIMITER ;
```

This assumes that you have defined a backup table by the name of `yourTableBackup` with the following table structure:

```sql
CREATE TABLE yourTableBackup (Product_id, Product_name, Pack_size, price, ts_of_backup);
```

With this backup table in place, you can fairly easily see the price history of a given product across time.  Should you need to restore historical price values, or look for trends, you are now setup to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to create a trigger like this:

```
CREATE TRIGGER `before_update_products` BEFORE UPDATE ON `products` FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        IF NEW.price <> OLD.price THEN
          SET NEW.price_change = CONCAT(OLD.price_change, ',', NEW.price);
        END IF;
END
```

It should tell your database to automatically append the new value of price to price_change when it is updated.

Answer (score 1):

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER tr_bu_products
BEFORE UPDATE
ON products
FOR EACH ROW
SET NEW.price_change = CONCAT(OLD.price_change, ',', NEW.price);
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=60c95c6fb91a2a56e08e09672c0bb394)

---

1. Do not forget to create BEFORE INSERT trigger which will insert initial `price` value into `price_change`.
2. Read carefully Tim's answer and alter your schema. Use this answer for studying purposes only.

PS. The trigger assumes that any UPDATE alters the price. If not then add according check into assigning value.